How to bold only e.g. the first, second, and second-to-last horizontal lines in a matplotlib table?
I'm working with matplotlib to create a table, and I need to bold specific horizontal lines.
Here's my current code:
np_table = table1(data)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 2.5))
ax.axis('off')

table = ax.table(cellText=np_table[1:],
                colLabels=np_table[0],
                cellLoc='center',
                loc='center',
                colWidths=[0.5, 0.5])

table.auto_set_font_size(False)
table.set_fontsize(9)
table.scale(0.5, 1.2)

rows, cols = len(np_table), len(np_table[0])
for (row, col), cell in table.get_celld().items():
    cell.set_linewidth(0.5)

    if row == 0:
        cell.set_text_props(weight='bold', color='black')

    if col == 0 and row > 0:
        cell.set_text_props(ha='left')

    cell.set_edgecolor('black')

plt.savefig('table.png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.1, dpi=300)
plt.close(fig)

I want to make the following modifications:
Bold the first horizontal line (top border of the header)
Bold the second horizontal line (bottom border of the header)
Bold the second-to-last horizontal line
All other lines should remain thin. How can I achieve this? I've tried adjusting the linewidth for specific cells, but I'm not sure how to target only these particular horizontal lines.
I'm constrained to use only the following libraries in Python for this task:
matplotlib,
numpy,
pandas,
seaborn
No other libraries or external tools are allowed.

Hello to stackoverflow!  You would get better / more support if your code had no dependency on data which only you have.
